# How do you run Jboss 4.2.0A as a service in Windows XP Pro

Tags: windows, jboss, service

I saw something once for wrappers used to do this but it asked for a licensing fee. Is there an open source way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"JBoss AS comes with Windows service executable as part of JBossNative
that can run JBoss Application Server as service.
The service executable jbosssvc.exe transforms the run.bat and
shutdown.bat batch scripts to services. This means that any change
made to those scripts will be used both in service and command
line mode."

http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/JBossNativeWindows

Answer (score 0):

A Problem I had was the remote Access to JBoss. In JBoss 4.2.3 you must start it with the Parameter `run.bat -b 0.0.0.0` to have access from other hosts.

I think since JBoss 4.2 remote access is turned off by default.

My solution was to adjust the :RESTART Section in the file run.bat like this:

```
:RESTART
"%JAVA%" %JAVA_OPTS% ^
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS%" ^
-classpath "%JBOSS_CLASSPATH%" ^
org.jboss.Main -b "0.0.0.0" %*
```